# ACF: Why can't I display all the images at once?

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day. 'sertificates_gallery' is the gallery ID from the Advanced Custom Fields. Tried also through foreach as in documentation, but it didn't work out. My code now looks like this:

```
$image = get_field('сertificates_gallery');
$size = 'thumbnail'; 

if( $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_link( $image, $size );
}
```

Comment: do `var_export($image);` before `if()` and show us what you got?

Comment: it just shows NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD:

```
    <?php 
    $images = acf_photo_gallery('сertificates_gallery', get_the_ID());

    if( $images ): ?>

      <div class="images">
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
      <?php echo $image['thumbnail_image_url']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php else : ?>
no certificates yet
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are trying to get the array, so you will need to do in the loop, Please check this [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/)

```
$image = get_field('сertificates_gallery');
$size = 'thumbnail'; 
foreach( $image as $single_image ):
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $single_image['ID'], $size );
endforeach;
```